requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 403 Client Error: Forbidden for url: - Open new link page
I'm trying to open a new link with this code:
                pagina_produto = url_base + link["href"]
                
                response = requests.get(pagina_produto, headers=hdr)
                response.raise_for_status()  # Levanta exceção para erros HTTP

                # Passar o conteúdo HTML para o BeautifulSoup
                sp = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
                print(sp.prettify())  # Exibir HTML formatado

                anuncio_ano = sp.find("div", class_="description__info-date big-space").text

but it gives me
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 403 Client Error: Forbidden for url: https://www.vivareal.com.br/imovel/apartamento-3-quartos-loteamento-villa-branca-bairros-jacarei-com-garagem-72m2-venda-RS645000-id-2737888129/

my headers is like this:
hdr = {
  "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.75 Safari/537.36",
  "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"
}

why is this problem occuring even when I've putted the headers? here is the complete code:
#imports
hdr = {
  "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.75 Safari/537.36",
  "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"
}


# Variáveis para armazenar dados
quantidade_2024 = 0
quantidade_2023 = 0
quantidade_2022 = 0
quantidade_2021 = 0
precos = []
tamanhos = []
data_planilha = []
precos_m2 = []
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
driver = uc.Chrome(options=options)
    #options.add_argument(f"--proxy-server={proxy}")    
    #options.add_argument("start-maximized")
    #options.add_argument("disable-infobars")options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
actions = ActionChains(driver)
data_planilha = []
precos_m2 = []
options.add_argument('--blink-settings=imagesEnabled=false')
# URL base (sem parâmetro de página para a primeira página)
url_linha = "https://www.vivareal.com.br/venda/sp/jacarei/bairros/loteamento-villa-branca/avenida-das-letras/#onde=,S%C3%A3o%20Paulo,Jacare%C3%AD,Bairros,Loteamento%20Villa%20Branca,Avenida%20das%20Letras,,,BR%3ESao%20Paulo%3ENULL%3EJacarei%3EBarrios%3ELoteamento%20Villa%20Branca,,,&quartos=2"
url_base = "https://www.vivareal.com.br"

# Função para obter o HTML da página

# Processar as páginas
tempo_inicial = time.time()
driver.get(url_linha)
pagina_produto = ""
try:
            
    botao_proximo = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@title = 'Próxima página']")))
    while True:
        
        pagina_atual = driver.page_source
        soup = BeautifulSoup(pagina_atual, "lxml")
        


        imoveis_container = soup.find("div", class_="results-list js-results-list")
        imoveis = imoveis_container.find_all("div")

        if not imoveis:
            print("Sem imóveis encontrados. Finalizando.")
            break  # Sai do loop se não houver imóveis na página

        for imovel in imoveis:
            
                # Obter tamanho
            tamanho = imovel.find("span", class_="property-card__detail-value").text
            tamanho = int(re.sub(r"\D", "", tamanho))  # Apenas números
            print(tamanho)
            tamanhos.append(tamanho)
            # Obter preço
            preco = imovel.find("div", class_="property-card__price").text
            preco = int("".join(re.findall(r"\d+", preco)))  # Apenas números
            print(preco)
            precos.append(preco)
            # Calcular preço por m²
            preco_m2 = preco / tamanho if tamanho else 0
            print(preco_m2)
            precos_m2.append(preco_m2)
            links = imovel.find_all("a", class_ = "property-card__content-link js-card-title")
            for link in links:
                pagina_produto = url_base + link["href"]
                
                response = requests.get(pagina_produto, headers=hdr)
                response.raise_for_status()  # Levanta exceção para erros HTTP

                # Passar o conteúdo HTML para o BeautifulSoup
                sp = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
                print(sp.prettify())  # Exibir HTML formatado

                anuncio_ano = sp.find("div", class_="description__info-date big-space").text
                if "2024" in anuncio_ano:
                    quantidade_2024 += 1
                elif "2023" in anuncio_ano:
                    quantidade_2023 += 1
                elif "2022" in anuncio_ano:
                    quantidade_2022 += 1
                elif "2021" in anuncio_ano:
                    quantidade_2021 += 1


        # Verificar se há próxima página (se não, interrompe)
        botao_proximo = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[@title = 'Próxima página']")
        valor = botao_proximo.get_attribute("data-page")

        if valor != "":
            driver.execute_script('arguments[0].click()', botao_proximo)
        else:
            break    
except NoSuchElementException:
    print("última página")

# Calcular médias
    quantidade_imoveis = len(precos)
    tamanho_medio = sum(tamanhos) / quantidade_imoveis if quantidade_imoveis else 0
    preco_medio_total = sum(precos) / quantidade_imoveis if quantidade_imoveis else 0
    precos_m2_total = sum(precos_m2) / quantidade_imoveis if quantidade_imoveis else 0

    # Salvar os dados na planilha
    data_planilha.append({
        'URL': url_base,
        'Número de anúncios': quantidade_imoveis,
        'Preço Médio': preco_medio_total,
        'Tamanho Médio': tamanho_medio,
        'Preço Médio por m2': precos_m2_total,
        'Anúncios de 2024': quantidade_2024,
        'Anúncios de 2023': quantidade_2023,
        'Anúncios de 2022': quantidade_2022,
        'Anúncios de 2021': quantidade_2021
    })

    df_planilha = pd.DataFrame(data_planilha)
    df_planilha.to_excel("catalogo_vivareal.xlsx", index=False)
    print("Planilha salva com sucesso!")
    print("--- %s segundos ---" % (time.time() - tempo_inicial))


you probably need credentials for that request.  Try logging in first.

Strange. The code scraps the search's page correctly, but it needs the credentials to go to the product's page? that's not the behavior of the manual navigation, btw.
